# WordPress Ajax product update?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wordpress, wp-plugin

**Выдает ошибку сервера 500**

**Ajax:**

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(document).on('change', '#menu_order', function(event) {
        var plugin_url = $(this).data('url'),
        product_id = $(this).data('product-id'),
        product_new_menu_order = $(this).val();

        jQuery.post(
            plugin_url,
            {
                'action': 'update_product',
                'data':  {
                    // 'action': 'update_product',
                    'product_id': product_id,
                    'product_new_menu_order': product_new_menu_order,
                },
            },
            function(response){
                alert('The server responded: ' + response);
            }
            );
    });
});
```

**И сам update:**

```
    $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
    $product_new_menu_order = $_POST['product_new_menu_order'];

function update_product() {
    $product = array(
        'ID'           => $product_id ,
        'menu_order' => $product_new_menu_order,
        );
    wp_update_post( $product );
    wp_die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_update_product', 'update_product');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_update_product', 'update_product');
```

Вот, в файл апдейта заходит,  принимает нужные данные, id поста, и новый порядок. Вот только хуки не отрабатывают, не позволяют обновить продукт, ошибка сервера 500.

**Как исправить?**

Comment: что в логах сервера?

Comment: Почему у вас инициализация `$product_id` и `$product_new_menu_order` находятся вне тела функции `update_product()`? Разумеется, при ajax-заросе значения post-переменных не передаются в функцию.

Comment: @Naumov - 
Notice: Функция has_cap вызвана с аргументом, который считается устаревшим с версии 2.0.0! Использование уровней пользователей в плагинах и темах считается устаревшим. Используйте роли и возможности.. in /var/www/timworld/data/www/timworld.info/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4020

Notice: Undefined variable: html in /var/www/timworld/data/www/timworld.info/wp-content/plugins/wc-dynamic-pricing-and-discounts/includes/classes/libraries/rightpress-updates.class.php on line 376

Comment: @Pyramidhead  по идее это делает их глобальными, на весь файл. Добавил в функцию - тот же результат. 


global $wpdb;
 $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
 $product_new_menu_order = $_POST['product_new_menu_order'];

 $product = array(
  'ID'           => $product_id ,
  'menu_order' => $product_new_menu_order,
  );
 wp_update_post( $product );
 wp_die();

Comment: @BonBonSlick, значения `$_POST` передаются ajax-ом непосредственно в функцию `update_product()`. Вне тела функции присвоение `$_POST['product_id']` и `$_POST['product_new_menu_order']` вернет `Undefined index`

Comment: @BonBonSlick, И что у вас в `$(this).data('url')`? По идее, там должен быть такой url `http://url-вашего-сайта/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`

Comment: @Pyramidhead там у меня url файла, который будет обновлять продукт. По этому ЮРЛ оно заходит в файл, и если там сразу задампить или вернуть что-то, оно вернет данные.

Comment: У вас там должен быть такой url `http://url-вашего-сайта/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`. Ознакомьтесь с тем, как работает ajax на WordPress.

Comment: @Pyramidhead поставил я туда ваш ЮРЛ, теперь оно возвращает только - 0

Comment: @Pyramidhead как тогда выбрать ЮРЛ файла который должен обработать Аджакс?

Comment: Вам не надо выбирать url файла. За вас всю работу сделают хуки `wp_ajax_update_product` и `wp_ajax_nopriv_update_product`. Добавил всю необходимую информацию в ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Перенесите инициализацию переменных `$product_id` и `$product_new_menu_order` в тело функции `update_product()`. Значения post-переменных передаются ajax-ом непосредственно в функцию `update_product()`.
2. Переменной `plugin_url` в вашем ajax запросе должно быть присвоено значение `http://url-вашего-сайта/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`, так как именно там находится обработчик AJAX.
3. Вместо `wp_die()` лучше использовать `wp_send_json_success()` и `wp_send_json_error()`.
4. Исправьте сам ajax-запрос:

```
jQuery.post(
    plugin_url,
    {
        action: 'update_product',
        product_id: product_id,
        product_new_menu_order: product_new_menu_order
    },
    function(response){
        alert('The server responded: ' + response);
    }
);
```

Comment: подключить рнр файл надо было еще. Добавьте 5-й пункт в ответ.include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/update_menu_order.php');